# Python, bs4 как извлечь текст между тегами

Tags: python, текст, bs4

Задача заключается в получении текста между тегами `<div class="_profile_online profile_online"><div class="profile_online_lv">`  и `<b class="mob_onl profile_mob_onl"  onclick="mobilePromo();" onmouseover="mobileOnlineTip(this, {mid: cur.oid, right: 1, was: 1})"></b></div> </div>', 'html.parser')`

(need find text between tags)

```
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome('D:\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('view-source:https://vk.com/id5')

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup('<div class="_profile_online profile_online"><div class="profile_online_lv">online<b class="mob_onl profile_mob_onl"  onclick="mobilePromo();" onmouseover="mobileOnlineTip(this, {mid: cur.oid, right: 1, was: 1})"></b></div> </div>', 'html.parser')
print(soup.div.text)
```

но суть в том что я в пемеренную soup вручную прописываю что в теге онлайн а мне нужно чтобы между тегами получить значение которое может меняться

Answer (score 0):

Конечно, вам ничего не надо обрезать. Вы подключили BeautifulSoup, но совершенно не используете его возможности. [Изучите статью](https://python-scripts.com/beautifulsoup-html-parsing)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup('<div class="_profile_online profile_online"><div class="profile_online_lv">online<b class="mob_onl profile_mob_onl"  onclick="mobilePromo();" onmouseover="mobileOnlineTip(this, {mid: cur.oid, right: 1, was: 1})"></b></div> </div>', 'html.parser')

print(soup.div.div.text)
```

Comment: так у меня если в теге явно описано значение текста - то после soup.div.text все выводится. тут суть в том что у меня значение между тегами может меняться и как мне его получать обновленное значение ?.

Comment: что вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: <div class="_profile_online profile_online"><div class="profile_online_lv">online<b class="mob_onl profile_mob_onl"  onclick="mobilePromo();" onmouseover="mobileOnlineTip(this, {mid: cur.oid, right: 1, was: 1})"></b></div> </div>', 'html.parser  где online это статус который может в динамике меняться.

Comment: у вас меняется код, уровень вложенности?

Comment: у меня меняются значения между тегами.

Comment: Тогда вы переодически опрашиваете сайт и парсите значение https://vc.ru/newtechaudit/109368-web-parsing-osnovy-na-python